# PL/SQL block fails in job but succeeds in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I created a PL/SQL block which gathers certain data from tables in my Oracle 12c database and writes them into a .csv file.
I cannot share the whole PL/SQL block but can outline the code

```
--create directory
str := q'{create directory DIR as '/tmp/tmp_dir'}';
execute immediate (str);

--get filename
select 'tmp_stat' || '.csv'
into filename
from dual;

--open file
tmp_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('DIR', filename, 'W', 32767);

--write header
UTL_FILE.put_line (tmp_file, 'col1;col2');

-- gather and write data
for stat in ([select statement]) LOOP
UTL_FILE.put_line (tmp_file, stat.dat);
END LOOP;
--close file
UTL_FILE.fclose (tmp_file);
```

When I run my code in SQL*Plus it works fine. But when I turn it into a job with the following options

- Raise Events: None
- Maximum Run Duration (minutes): None
- Priority: Medium
- Schedule Limit (minutes): None
- Maximum Runs: None
- Maximum Failures: None
- Job Weight: 1
- Instance Stickiness: TRUE

When I try to run the job with the exact same code (except the / to mark the end of the block), I get the error

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at line 61
```

I don't have a line 536 in my code, but line 61 is

```
tmp_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('DIR', filename, 'W', 32767);
```

Any suggestions on why the error is raised when executing the code is a job?

Comment: Try to do the following
1. Connect to the database by the user using which you were tring to run this block.
2. Query all_directories and see if the directory you are using listed out there.
3.If not then connect sys grant read,write on this directory to your schema.

Comment: The directory is listed but it is owned by sys user.

Comment: please provide chmod on that directory.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x is chmod

Comment: If you change the permissions to: rwxrwsrwx, does it work?

Comment: please refer to this. [ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at “SYS.UTL_FILE”, line 536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014884/ora-29283-invalid-file-operation-ora-06512-at-sys-utl-file-line-536)

Comment: Changing the permissions does not work. I have another job scheduled two times a day doing a similiar thing except on a different directory and this job works fine. The directory has the same permissions and the db user has the same privileges on the object. I cannot explain the behaviour to me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that I had all the permissions and privileges set right except I forgot to create the directory on the second node too.

So whenever the job ran on the second instance (which it by chance did) the error was raised that the file could not be written.

---

Of course it had to be as simple as that but I want to post it as an answer anyway.

*When working with an Oracle RAC your mantra should always be "Keep in mind the other instances."*